# Efficiently grouping one model based on another's ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models, roughly:

```
class Event(model.Model):
    pass

class Judgement(model.Model):
    grade = models.CharField()
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
```

Given N possible `grades`, I want to class `Event`s into N+2 groups:

- `Event`s, where all the `Judgement`s for a given `Event` are all the same (N groups)
- `Event`s with no `Judgement`
- `Event`s with conflicting `Judgement`s

So far I just want to either the count of all the groups, or the results from one of the groups.  I have some really ugly code where I just loop through all the objects looking at the `<foreignkey>_set` attribute, but it doesn't seem to use Django's ORM that effectively:

#### Getting the count of all the groups

```
def event_group_counts():
    data = defaultdict(int, {})
    events = Event.objects.prefetch_related('judgement_set').all()
    for event in events:
        grades = set(e.grade for e in event.judgement_set.all())
        if len(grades) > 1:
            data['disagree'] += 1
        elif len(grades) < 1:
            data['unjudged'] += 1
        else:
            data[grades.pop()] += 1
```

#### Getting all of one group

```
def event_group(group):
    results = []
    events = Event.objects.prefetch_related('judgement_set').all()
    for event in events:
        grades = set(e.grade for e in event.judgement_set.all())
        if len(grades) > 1 and group == 'disagree':
            results.append(event)
        elif len(grades) < 1 and group == 'unjudged':
            results.append(event)
        elif group == grades.pop():
            results.append(event)
```

The alternative might be to determine the group the `Event` belongs in when `Judgement` objects are saved, but if I can avoid that then yay.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [aggregation functions?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id6) This is how I would do it:

- first, name your one to many relationship `event = models.ForeignKey(Event, related_name='judgements')`
- for the count, do something like this `q = Event.objects.annotate(Count('judgements'), distinct=True)`. You can access this new field with `judgements__count`.
- for retrieving a certain group, use filtering and ordering:

Maybe something like this:

```
def event_group(group):

    # unjudged is a special case, you just get all events with an empty set of judgements 

    judgements = Judgement.objects.filter(grade=group_id).order_by(event)
    event_ids = [j.event for j in set(judgements)]
    return Event.objects.filter(id__in=event_ids)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: `id__in` causes my DB interface to die when it gets up in to the thousands; `OperationalError: too many SQL variables`.  Still mulling this.